# Lex-sorting a pandas series/dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, lexicographic

Hi I have a data frame which has the following values as input

{1,20,21,10,100,1000,30}

I need the output to be sorted as {1,10,100,1000,20,21,30}

What is the best way to do this, I have more than 20000 values to be sorted in the above format.

I tried sort_values but its not helping .

Thanks

Comment: That's not a dataframe. Can you please actually clarify what you want?

Comment: If it _was_ a dataframe, you would do `df['col'].astype(str).sort_values()` - string conversion ensures lexical sort.

Comment: I have it in a data frame only, I have just given a data frame in that format.

Comment: Well, look down, I've taken a stab at this question, unclear as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a series of the form:

```
s

0       1
1      20
2      21
3      10
4     100
5    1000
6      30
dtype: int64
```

To lex-sort this series, you'd need to first cast to string and *then* call `sort_values`.

```
s.astype(str).sort_values()

0       1
3      10
4     100
5    1000
1      20
2      21
6      30
dtype: object
```

---

In the case of a dataframe, you'd have to do something similar:

```
df['Col'] = df['Col'].astype(str)
df.sort_values(subset=['Col'])
df['Col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Col'])
```

As an improvement to this, I'd recommend argsort for the task, followed by a little indexing magic with `iloc`.

```
idx = df['Col'].astype(str).argsort()
df = df.iloc[idx]
```

With this approach, you don't have to persist the cast before a `sort_values` call.

Comment: Thats so so so exact

Comment: @Bharathshetty Fun fact: You can exploit `df.argsort` here.

Comment: `df[0].astype(str).sort_values().astype(int)` maybe but i loved argsort